# How to ask about salary range before accepting an interview?

Tags: resume, new-job, email

I have applied for a job online and I received a reply from them agreeing for me to interview with this company. However, I was told that I would need to take a month long training course.

Additionally they did not say anything about potential salary in the email although information on the salary range was written in the  job adverts.

I want to be sure of the salary because I would have to move states to work for them.
I want to know if the training period will be paid or not and if the salary range is the same as in the job advert.

Should I ask them these questions and are they ok to ask through email? How could I go about asking them these questions if email is not an acceptable medium?

```
And They wrote in advertising :
*Annual compensation between $40k- $80k 
*FREE Accommodation 
*Relocation Assistance 
*6 to 7 weeks Classes : FREE Skill Enhancement Training Programs
```

how to ask politely in email  :

```
Is the training period paid or not?
Is means that my salary will be between this range ?
```

because I will working as entry level

Comment: is this a real estate position?  If so it is probably selling time shares and it is largely a scam.  over 90% of the people will be let go before they can actually get their licence to sell real estate or make anything much above minimum wage.

Comment: Thanks

how to ask politely in email :
1)Is the training period paid or not?
2)Is means that my salary will be between this range ?
because english is not perfect Help me please :)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere It seems like they are asking for a commitment of time and training *before* the actual interview. (Which is dodgy in its own right.)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I did say it was *dodgy*; its only nonsense if you assume they are playing the same game everyone else is. As the  accepted answer points out, this isn't always the case. Training scams (pay for the training, no promises), Recruit farming (You will "pass" regardless, and be sold on to a client as a "trained" canidate), etc, etc.   This stuff isn't new.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you don't pay 1 penny for instruction, there are companies that exist that try to lure you in to paying for the instruction course with the promise of a great job at the end.  But the jobs are not guaranteed, and often do not exist with the company you interviewed with but rather they bring in recruiters from other companies.

To answer your question, of course you have to make all these inquiries, or else, if they are serious, they could think you are gullible or desperate. If you perceive they are evasive or bothered by your questions, run away immediately.

Don't be concerned too much of judgment. Be yourself. If they are not going to like you it's just better to know in advance  :-)  No?

As to the way to ask, I am not the most reliable source as I am not a native english.
I would probably ask this way (please, a native speaker come to rescue):

- I would like to know whether the training period follows the date of hire, and what is the remuneration during this period.
- I would also like to know, in case I am hired, what is the average starting salary for an employee in a position similar to mine, and what are the growth opportunities.

(Clearly, if they ask you to do the "training" before hire, just run, and fast :-) )

Comment: Hi Pam, welcome to the workplace! This isn't really an answer to the question on How to ask about salary ranges before the interview, it seems more like your views on the problem which is probably more suited to leaving a comment on the original question (which you can't do until 50 rep). You can however edit this to make it an answer if you think you have one! If not you can always ask for help in [chat] if you so need!

Comment: I tried to help you out by expanding your first paragraph.  I explained why they need to look out for scammers.  I suggest you expand your other 2 paragraphs to similarly explain what they need to inquire about and how to ask.  That is what the question is really asking for

Comment: Thanks how to ask politely in email : 1)Is the training period paid or not? 2)Is means that my salary will be between this range ? because english is not perfect Help me please :)

Comment: Added some hints about that

Comment: btw, let us know if it turned out ok. At this point we are all curious :-) Best of luck for your future!

Comment: one **BIG** thing - *never* **ever** use contractions in professional emails, *especially* early in the process. The few characters you save by typing "I'd" instead of "I would" are not worth it!